# Separating of normed space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $X$is a normed space and $Y$  is subspace of $X^*$ , I need to show that every $weak^*$ dense subset of $X^*$ separates points in $x$.For this I have shown Y separates $0$ and $X$,but how can I show that if its separates 0 and X then it is separating $x,y$ for $x\neq y$.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "it separates 0 and $X$"

Comment: I have shown that $Y$ separates only $0$ and $x$ not all the points.

Answer (score 1):

If you have shown that $Y$ can separate zero from all the other points in $X$, you have simply shown that $Y$ separates $X$. Because if you take $x \neq y$ in $X$, then $y-x \neq 0$ so there's a $f \in Y$ such that $f(0) \neq f(x-y)$. Since $f$ is linear, we finally have $f(x) \neq f(y)$.